# How to change permissions for a USB adapter?

Tags: usb, permissions, ham-radio

I have an RS232 to USB adapter and I need to change permissions on /dev/ttyUSB0 to make a ham radio interface program work.

So far I have tried `sudo` at the command line with no success.
I tried `sudo nautilus` and was able to make the permission changes using the GUI, and then the program worked, however, when I re-booted the machine, the permissions were re-set to "root".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In Terminal type the following:
`sudo adduser "User Name" dialout`

**Example:**
The User Name on my computer is **gordy** so I would type in Terminal
`sudo adduser gordy dialout` then press <kbd>enter</kbd>

I then see a message, stating that `gordy` has been added to dialout group
Type `groups` to see what groups a "User Name " belongs to, and you should have access to the USB ports.